change value of dropdown based on two other dropdown menus
I'm trying to make it so that when the user chooses a specific station and direction from their respective dropdown menus, it shows different timeslots in the timeslot dropdown as well. the snippet for the dropdowns is here:
<div class="input-box" id="station-box">
                  <span class="details">Station</span>
                  <select name="station" id="station" required>
                    <option value="">Pinagbuhatan</option>
                    <option value="">Kalawaan</option>
                    <option value="">San Joaquin</option>
                    <option value="">Guadalupe</option>
                    <option value="">Hulo</option>
                    <option value="">Valenzuela</option>
                    <option value="">Lambingan</option>
                    <option value="">Sta-Ana</option>
                    <option value="">PUP</option>
                    <option value="">Quinta</option>
                    <option value="">Lawton</option>
                    <option value="">Escolta</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="details">Direction</span>
                    <select name="direction" id="direction" required>
                        <option value="downstream">Downstream</option>
                        <option value="upstream">Upstream</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="details">Timeslot</span>
                    <select name="timeslot" id="timeslot" required>
                      <option value=""></option>
                  </select>
                  </div>

window.onload = function() {
    // Stations and their respective timeslots
    var stations = {
        'Pinagbuhatan': {
            'Upstream': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
            'Downstream': ['D', 'E', 'F']
        },
        'Kalawaan': {
            'Upstream': ['G', 'H', 'I'],
            'Downstream': ['J', 'K', 'L']
        }
    };
    
    // Get references to the station, direction, and timeslot dropdowns
    var stationSelect = document.getElementById('station');
    var directionSelect = document.getElementById('direction');
    var timeslotSelect = document.getElementById('timeslot');
  
    // Function to populate the timeslot dropdown based on the selected station and direction
    function populateTimeslots() {
        var selectedStation = stationSelect.value;
        var selectedDirection = directionSelect.value;
        
        // Clear out any existing options
        timeslotSelect.innerHTML = '';
        
        // If both station and direction are selected
        if (selectedStation && selectedDirection) {
            // Get the timeslots associated with the selected station and direction
            var timeslots = stations[selectedStation][selectedDirection];
            
            // Populate the timeslot dropdown with the timeslots
            timeslots.forEach(function(timeslot) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = timeslot;
                option.textContent = timeslot;
                timeslotSelect.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
    }
    
    // Attach change event listeners to the station and direction dropdowns
    stationSelect.addEventListener('change', populateTimeslots);
    directionSelect.addEventListener('change', populateTimeslots);
      
    // Populate the timeslot dropdown initially
    populateTimeslots();
};

I've been testing with the first two stations at first, but to no avail. I'm guessing it's with how the stations are called since there's a category for the station and sub-categories for whether upstream or downstream, but I'm stumped on how I would fix that.

Add value attributes to the <option> elements of the Stations <select> element:
<select name="station" id="station" required>
  <option value="Pinagbuhatan">Pinagbuhatan</option>
  <option value="Kalawaan">Kalawaan</option>

Ideally, the values should correspond to the first level keys in the stations dictionary variable in the JavaScript. This is so that stationSelect.value in populateTimeslots() gets the station name we expect.
Furthermore, consider changing the Upstream and Downstream second level keys in the stations dictionary variable to lowercase – upstream and downstream respectively. This is so that this matches the value attribute values of the Direction <select> element.
Doing both of these things will mean that the stationSelect.value and directionSelect.value (that are assigned to selectedStation and selectedDirection respectively) will be able to traverse to a value that exists when used in stations[selectedStation][selectedDirection].


window.onload = function () {
  // Stations and their respective timeslots
  var stations = {
    Pinagbuhatan: {
      upstream: ["A", "B", "C"],
      downstream: ["D", "E", "F"],
    },
    Kalawaan: {
      upstream: ["G", "H", "I"],
      downstream: ["J", "K", "L"],
    },
  };

  // Get references to the station, direction, and timeslot dropdowns
  var stationSelect = document.getElementById("station");
  var directionSelect = document.getElementById("direction");
  var timeslotSelect = document.getElementById("timeslot");

  // Function to populate the timeslot dropdown based on the selected station and direction
  function populateTimeslots() {
    var selectedStation = stationSelect.value;
    var selectedDirection = directionSelect.value;

    // Clear out any existing options
    timeslotSelect.innerHTML = "";

    // If both station and direction are selected
    if (selectedStation && selectedDirection) {
      // Get the timeslots associated with the selected station and direction
      var timeslots = stations[selectedStation][selectedDirection];

      // Populate the timeslot dropdown with the timeslots
      timeslots.forEach(function (timeslot) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = timeslot;
        option.textContent = timeslot;
        timeslotSelect.appendChild(option);
      });
    }
  }

  // Attach change event listeners to the station and direction dropdowns
  stationSelect.addEventListener("change", populateTimeslots);
  directionSelect.addEventListener("change", populateTimeslots);

  // Populate the timeslot dropdown initially
  populateTimeslots();
};
<div class="input-box" id="station-box">
  <span class="details">Station</span>
  <select name="station" id="station" required>
    <option value="Pinagbuhatan">Pinagbuhatan</option>
    <option value="Kalawaan">Kalawaan</option>
    <option value="">San Joaquin</option>
    <option value="">Guadalupe</option>
    <option value="">Hulo</option>
    <option value="">Valenzuela</option>
    <option value="">Lambingan</option>
    <option value="">Sta-Ana</option>
    <option value="">PUP</option>
    <option value="">Quinta</option>
    <option value="">Lawton</option>
    <option value="">Escolta</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <span class="details">Direction</span>
  <select name="direction" id="direction" required>
    <option value="downstream">Downstream</option>
    <option value="upstream">Upstream</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <span class="details">Timeslot</span>
  <select name="timeslot" id="timeslot" required>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>



